# "Know the way over"

Tags: american-english

You tell someone that, if a disaster happen at your place, you're going to go to his/her place (kidding).

They reply: "I am glad you still know the way over".

What does this mean?

Comment: Means you haven't visited your friend in a while. Time to pay him a call :)

Comment: “Know the way over” is not an expression; “over” simply means “over to my house”, and “know the way” is meant quite literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "I'm glad you still know the way over" is an incomplete sentence. Over, in this case, is an adverb before a prepositional phrase that was omitted here. The full sentence would be "I'm glad you still know the way over **to my house**."

The meaning here is that the speaker is happy that you can remember how to get to their house. 
The implication, more subtly, is that they would like you to visit more. By implying that it's odd that you remember how to get there still, they're effectively saying "you don't visit much" and would probably like that to change.

Comment: The *over* in *are you coming over* is an adverb, not a preposition. See, e.g. M-W: "[1h. to one's home *invite some friends over*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over)."

Comment: @choster Thank you for the correction. I didn't know that distinction. Edited for new info.